# Reconstruct / extend data.frame previously collapsed on a subgroup ID within each group ID

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is to ask you how to "reconstruct" a data frame that was previously collapsed based of the segment_id.  containing start and end variables into a table that extend to each element within every interval.

Considering the following sample dataset:

```
my_df <- structure(list(group_id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
                            3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
                            7, 7, 7, 8, 9), start = c(1L, 1L, 13L, 24L, 1L, 16L, 30L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 20L, 
                                                                                 1L, 1L), end = c(22L, 13L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 30L, 51L, 14L, 
                                                                                                      26L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 17L, 9L, 20L, 26L, 17L, 14L), segment_id = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                     1L)), row.names = 3377225:3377242, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("group_id", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         "start", "end", "segment_id"))
```

**It is critical to apply the following pre-processing:**

```
my_df [my_df $start > 1, "start"] <- my_df [my_df $start > 1, "start"] +1
```

As you can observe in the data, the information `segment_id` was used to collapse the `data.frame` and the `start` and `end` element of each `segment` were kept in variables `start` and `end` respectively.

I am struggling to find an efficient solution that can run over several millions records and present the following result:

```
group_id <- c(rep(1, 22), rep(2, 27), rep(3, 51), rep(4, 26), rep(5, 8), rep(6, 17), rep(7, 26), rep(8, 17), rep(9, 14))
element_id <- c(seq.int(1, 22), seq.int(1, 27), seq.int(1, 51), seq.int(1, 26), seq.int(1, 8), seq.int(1, 17), seq.int(1, 26), seq.int(1, 17), seq.int(1, 14))
segment_id <- c(rep(1, 22), rep(1, 13), rep(2, (24-13)), rep(3, (27-24)), rep(1, 16), rep(2, (30-16)), rep(3, (51-30)), rep(1, 14), rep(2, (26-14)), rep(1, 8), rep(1, 6), rep(2, (11-6)), rep(3, (17-11)), rep(1, 9), rep(2, (20-9)), rep(3, (26-20)), rep(1, 17), rep(1,14))

solution_df <- data.frame(group_id, element_id, segment_id)
```

The only solution I found implies to convert the data.frame in matrix and perform a loop over all the segments.

To clarify, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: I see that the `start` and `end` values are not always consistent when you reshape your dataset. For example, for `group_id = 2` and `segment_id = 2` you have `start = 13`, but in the reshaped dataset it starts from 14. Is that a pattern or a mistake?

Comment: thank you for your question. It is a "pattern" in the sense that for all the element_id > 1, the idea is that of a ( ; ] mathematics interval. This means that that the `element_id = 13` is in` segment_id = 1` and `element_id = 14 `is in `segment_id = 2`. Is this clear or I should improve the explanation?

Comment: Great I got it. I'll update my solution.

Comment: However, it just happens here to have this pattern for element_id > 1, with a different dataset you might had this issue when element_id = 1, right? It's better to try and find a more general solution.

Comment: You are right I should apply some preprocessing to the mydf in order to avoid the pattern/overlapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_df <- structure(list(group_id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9), 
start = c(1L, 1L, 13L, 24L, 1L, 16L, 30L, 1L, 14L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 11L, 1L, 9L, 20L, 1L, 1L), 
end = c(22L, 13L, 24L, 27L, 16L, 30L, 51L, 14L, 26L, 8L, 6L, 11L, 17L, 9L, 20L, 26L, 17L, 14L), 
segment_id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L)), 
row.names = 3377225:3377242, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("group_id", "start", "end", "segment_id"))


library(tidyverse)

my_df %>%
  mutate(start = ifelse(start > 1 , start + 1, start)) %>%          # update start values
  group_by(group_id, segment_id) %>%                                # for each group and segment id combination
  nest() %>%                                                        # create a dataset with the rest of the columns
  mutate(element_id_new = map(data, ~ seq(.$start, .$end, 1))) %>%  # get a sequence of values from start to end
  unnest(element_id_new)                                            # unnest the sequence

# # A tibble: 208 x 3
#   group_id segment_id element_id_new
#      <dbl>      <int>          <dbl>
# 1        1          1              1
# 2        1          1              2
# 3        1          1              3
# 4        1          1              4
# 5        1          1              5
# 6        1          1              6
# 7        1          1              7
# 8        1          1              8
# 9        1          1              9
# 10       1          1             10
# # ... with 198 more rows
```

Comment: While I like this answer and think it is the solution to the problem the output does not match `solution_df` in the question. I trust `solution_df` should be corrected.

Comment: @missuse Answer updated. I think the general pattern is that within a group id, each segment id should not finish when the next starts.

Comment: @AntoniosK thank you but `identical(antoniosK$segment_id_new, solution_df$segment_id)` is `FALSE` :(

Comment: Even after updating the answer? I get the same number of rows (208).

Comment: I got it! I've used wrong column name. We're updating the element ids, not the segment ids.... :-) It should work now.

Comment: Good. I've added your pre-procesing process on my code. That should works as expected and much faster than processing values at the end.

Comment: identical doesn't mean equal. It's something more! :-) Try this `identical(as.numeric(dd$segment_id), as.numeric(solution_df$segment_id))`

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative approach using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_df)[start == 1, start := 0][
  , .(group_id = rep(group_id, end - start), segment_id = rep(segment_id, end - start))][
      , element_id := rowid(group_id)][]
```

> ```
>      group_id segment_id element_id
>   1:        1          1          1
>   2:        1          1          2
>   3:        1          1          3
>   4:        1          1          4
>   5:        1          1          5
>  ---                               
> 204:        9          1         10
> 205:        9          1         11
> 206:        9          1         12
> 207:        9          1         13
> 208:        9          1         14
> ```

#### Explanation

The requested correction is applied - but in a different way as suggested by the OP - only to those few entries where `start == 1`. This reduces the number of updates *in place*, i.e., without copying the whole object and we can avoid to add `+ 1` when computing the lengths of each streak.

Then `group_id` and `segment_id` are repeated as many times as requested by `end - start`. Finally, the `element_id` is appended by numbering the rows within each `group_id` using the `rowid()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, I always like data.table solutions because are very efficient. I will perform a benchmark and post the results to define which is the best answer!

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to see your BM results and how they scale with problem size.